# SEDE does not draw lines on execution plan when plan is very complex

Tags: bug, data-explorer

In the execution plan for [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/671679), the lines between the boxes are not drawn:

[image]

I am not sure if it is related to the number of boxes, or if it is because of the dimensions of the plan.

Chrome 58, Windows